# Query to obtain staff related (pivot table)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this models:

```
STAFF
-----
id
name


PAGE_STAFF
----------
page_id
staff_id


PAGE
----
id
title
parent_id



PARENT_PAGE
-----------
id
title
```

And relationship methods like this:

```
     in Staff Model
     /**
     * The areas that belongs to the staff member.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function pages()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class);
    }


   in Page Model
   /**
   * The staff that belongs to the page.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
   */

   public function staff()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Staff::class);
   }
```

PARENT_PAGE contains id (and title) of "main page". This model is not connected with any model and I use it for filter ocurrences. I mean I only need page_id from page_staff that parent_page.id == page_staff.page_id.

But I need to know entries in pivot table "page_staff". The query needed is

all staff members (page_staff.staff_id) that are contained in "page_staff" model and page_staff.page_id == parent_page.id.

After this I need all staff models (staff.id)

How can I do this in Eloquent?

Best regards

Comment: How is staff connected to parent_page? there is no parent_page_id anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little confused on how ParentPage is connected in all of this. To get all staff there is in the pivot table, we can do it with `has()`. Will update the question, when i know where the parent page is in this domain.

```
$staffWithPages = Staff::whereHas('pages.parent', function ($query) {
    $query->where('laravel_reserved_0.id', '!=', 'page_staff.page_id');
})->get();
```

If you want the id's use the `Laravel Collection` pluck method.

```
$staffWithPages->plukc('id')->all();
```

Comment: I thiks that this is correct: `$staffWithPages = Staff::has('pages')->get();` but like you say. Relationship with parent_page is only get occurrences (may be: where page.parent_id == parent_page.id) ¿?

Comment: you can just do has('pages.parent'), this will fetch all staff that has pages with parents, is that the logic you want?

Comment: No. I need "all staff members contained in page_staff. But only with page_staff.page_id == parent_page.id"

Comment: Not at all. `$staffWithPages = Staff::has('pages.parent')->get()` return staff members contained in page_staff (with pages) but this result is not filtered by parent_page.id. `where page_staff.page_id == parent_page.id` filter is missing. How Can include this in the query?

Comment: Updated the question, where flaky not having to test it, but see if it helps if any error occurs, i will assist

Comment: Sorry. Im wrong. I need all staff member contained in PAGE_STAFF. where page_staff.page_id == page.id AND  page.parent_id == parent_page.id

Comment: I tried: `'staff' => Staff::whereHas('pages.parent', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('page_staff.page_id', 'page.id')
                            ->where('page.parent_id', 'parent_page.id');
                })->get()` but not show any file

Comment: can you try just with $query->where('parent_page.id', '!=', 'page_staff.page_id'); and ensure your data reflects this query would work

Comment: I got this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'parent_page.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `staff` where exists (select * from `page` inner join `page_staff` on `page`.`id` = `page_staff`.`page_id` where `staff`.`id` = `page_staff`.`staff_id` and exists (select * from `page` as `laravel_reserved_0` where `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `page`.`parent_id` and `parent_page`.`id` != page_staff.page_id and `laravel_reserved_0`.`deleted_at` is null) and `page`.`deleted_at` is null) and `staff`.`deleted_at` is null)`

Comment: aghrr yh it joins the same table with the parent structure, see if     $query->where('laravel_reserved_0.id', '!=', 'page_staff.page_id'); can help you, not the best solution but let's get you to somewhere you can fix it :)

Comment: I simply don't know what you mean by filtered by parent id, when i read the question again it seems like has('pages.parent'); should work,

Comment: Every page have a parent_id. Then every page_id result of the query needs to have parent_id == parent_page.id. In other case dont get